# Minimum number of samples on a CNN

Tags: dataset, conv-neural-network

Related to [this paper](https://sci-hub.tw/https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/11427445_73), could it also be applied to convolutional neural networks? I ask this because FNN and CNN share many characteristics.

The entry for this CNN are images.

This is the formula:

[image]

Where `Ne` it is Entry Layers, `Nc` it is Hidden Layers, `Ns` it is Output Layers and `Nej` it is the minimum number of samples needed for training.

Any answer is welcome.

Answer (score 0):

**CNN is a feed forward neural network** that is generally used for Image recognition and object classification. So, the answer it is **yes**.